# Deequ satisfies function not behaving as expected

Tags: pyspark, amazon-deequ

I am using pydeequ to run some checks on data, however it is not behaving as expected. One of my columns should contain any values between 0 and 1. The data looks like this

```
|col 1      |
| 0.5635412 |
| 0.123     |
| 1.0       |


check = Check(spark, CheckLevel.Warning, "DQ Check")
result = VerificationSuite(spark)\
    .onData(df)\
    .addCheck(check
        .satisfies("col1 BETWEEN 0 AND 1", "range check", lambda x: x==1))\
    .run()

result_df = VerificationResult.checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, result)
```

THe result is returning a failure with the message

Value: 0.5635412 does not meet the constraint requirement!

Can anyone advise on where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example? I wasn't able to reproduce it with the elements you gave.

Comment: I found the issue, there was a null value in my data that I hadn't accounted for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised there were a couple of null values in the data I hadn't expected.

Updated code to

```
check = Check(spark, CheckLevel.Warning, "DQ Check")
result = VerificationSuite(spark)\
.onData(df)\
.addCheck(check
    .satisfies("col1 BETWEEN 0 AND 1 OR col1 IS NULL", "range check", lambda x: x==1))\
.run()

result_df = VerificationResult.checkResultsAsDataFrame(spark, result)
```

Comment: Can you explain the usage of 'lambda x: x==1' here?